# superfish boostrap4 responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I try superfish with boostrap 4 and update for responsive using.
I inserted this code but it does'nt work well.

Do you have an idea to change the elements ?

Thanks

```
<style>
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height:1.50rem;
}

.sf-menu li {
  position: relative;
}
.sf-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.sf-menu > li {
  float: left;
}
.sf-menu li:hover > ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.sf-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.sf-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.sf-menu ul {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  min-width: 12em; /* allow long menu items to determine submenu width */
  *width: 12em; /* no auto sub width for IE7, see white-space comment below */
}

.sf-menu a {
  border-left: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dFeEFF; /* fallback colour must use full shorthand */
  border-top: 1px;
  padding: .75em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  zoom: 1; /* IE7 */
}
.sf-menu a {
  color: #373a3c;
  font-size: 13px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.sf-menu li {
  white-space: nowrap; /* no need for Supersubs plugin */
  *white-space: normal; /* ...unless you support IE7 (let it wrap) */
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  height:30px;
}

.sf-menu ul li {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.sf-menu ul ul li {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.sf-menu li:hover,
.sf-menu li.sfHover {
/*  background-color: #747474;*/
  /* only transition out, not in */
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}


.backgroundSuperfish {
  background-image: url(../images/menu_superfish.gif);
  height:1.90rem;
}

.headerLine {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height:0.05rem;
}

.current {
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.current li:hover,
.current li.sfHove {
  background-color: #FFEEC2;
  color:#747474;
}


.subLevel {
  color:#373a3c;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 5px!important;
}

.subLevel li:hover,
.subLevel li.sfHover{
  background-color: #FFEEC2;
  color:#747474;
}


.topLevel {
  color:#373a3c;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 5px!important;
}

.topLevel li:hover,
.topLevel li.sfHover {
  background-color: #FFEEC2;
  color:#747474;
}

.imageheaderMenu {
}
</style>
```

html code with boostrap4

```
<div class="backgroundSuperfish">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsiveCollapse">☰</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="responsiveCollapse"> <!-- class .navbar-toggleable-* -->
      <span class="pull-md-left">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav sf-menu" id="example">
          <li class="nav-item current">Home
             <ul>
               <li class="nav-item topLevel"><span><a href="../index.php">Store</a></span></li>
               <li class="nav-item topLevel"><span><a href="index.php">Back Office</a></span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item current">Configuration
             <ul>
               <li class="nav-item current subLevel"><span class="imageheaderMenu"><img src="/images/menu/configuration.gif" alt="" height="10" />&nbsp;</span><span>My store</span>
                 <ul>
                   <li class="nav-item topLevel"><a href="configuration.php?gID=1">General configuration</a></li>
                   <li class="nav-item topLevel"><a href="configuration.php?gID=25">Laws & regulations</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </li>
             </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

the script with superfish

```
<script>
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#example').superfish({
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work well? What is the problem?

Comment: The pb come from superfish, maybe boostrap 4 is too new, i am not a specialist, that 's why my question